# What is this "Egyptian Coffee"?

Tags: coffee, food-identification

I came across [this video](https://www.facebook.com/borayeter/videos/857699977644486/) on Facebook, which allegedly demonstrates some sort of "Egyptian Coffee" making technique. What exactly is the video showing? Where can I read more about this coffee making technique, and the associated equipment, etc?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually the Turkish method for making coffee, or a variant of it. Coffee grounds, cold water and sugar are brought *just* to a boil several times before being poured into small cups. For this method one typically uses the finest possible grind of coffee.

The sand is used to control heat. The pots (called *cezve*) on top of the sand keep warm, and when you want them to boil you push them down through the sand to make direct contact with the hot plate underneath.

Comment: They make it the same way in Greece, where the pot is called a *briki*. Stoves in Greece usually come with a small burner that's just the right size for a briki. This gives much less control than a bed of sand but is, of course, much more practical for home use. (Watch. It. Like. A. Hawk. If it boils over, it's one heck of a mess to clean up, especially on an electric stove.)

Comment: Same in Russia, it's second most popular method after instant coffee, using stove instead of sand.

Comment: I always get edgy when the verb "to boil" is used in combination with "coffee", while at the same time not clearly indicating that coffee _should not boil, ever_, but I assume you used _just_ to indicate that, so  +1. It's the same method as Turkish coffee, and still widely in use in any country that was a part of the Ottoman empire.